# FIFO commands in bash script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm trying to find out whether there is a command that allows calling another script and treating these calls in FIFO order.

E.G.: script A works in an infinite loop.  In this loop, 10 successive requests are made to execute script B.  *However,* script B may only be executed when its previous request was ended.  Script A has to continue working while the 10 requested scripts B are successively executed.

Comment: Very ambiguous question IMHO. Can you explain a bit more what exactly you want ? Each script is executed in their own subshell, and for each subshell a separate process is created, so inherently it is FIFO order.

Answer (score 3):

The `wait` builtin of shell is designed to solve exactly this purpose, to wait for some process (or processes) to finish and collect it's exit status.

You can:

- Run `script_A` in an infinite loop or `exit` if it spawns and finishes executing 10 instances of `script_B`
- With `script_A`, use a looping construct, within the loop, send the `script_B` to background, get its PID using `$!`
- Wait for the process to finish by `wait PID`
- Do this 10 times
- Exit from `script_A`, or continue with something else

So you can make `script_A` as:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    echo "Run $i :: script_B"
    /path/to/script_B &
    pid=$!
    wait "$pid"
done
```

If you want to continue doing something else, append them after the `for` construct.

Just for the sake of completeness, if you want to continue/break out based on the exit status of the last `scrip_B`, add a short check for the exit status too:

```
#!/bin/bash                                                                  
for ((i=1; i<=10; i++)); do
    echo "Run $i :: script_B"
    /path/to/script_B &
    pid=$!
    wait "$pid" && continue
    break
done
```

Comment: Better then mine! +1

Answer (score 1):

What I use in a script to prevent it from being executed twice is a status file, but you can easily adapt that same system to allow scripts being executed in FIFO mode:

E.g. in below example, the script will just exit if it's already running:

```
#!/bin/bash 

if [ -f /var/tmp/backup.bsy ]; then 
    # backup already running, log and exit
    exit; 
fi

# Set backup status to "Busy"
mv /var/tmp/backup.ok /var/tmp/backup.bsy

# perform backup here

# Set backup status to "Done"
mv /var/tmp/backup.bsy /var/tmp/backup.ok
```

and it's trivial to change the `exit` to a loop that `sleep`s a few seconds/minutes (depending on your usage requirements) and looks whether `script.1`, `script.2`, `script.3`, `script.4`, ... exists and executes them in the correct order...

#### ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but can't you just place the invocations of `scriptB` within a command group (or subshell), and background *that* so that the *group* is executed asynchronously e.g.

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Submiting B command group at: $(date)"

{
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
  ./scriptB
} &

echo "Continuing to work at: $(date)"

exit
```

where for the sake of illustration, `scriptB` is just

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Starting B at: $(date)"
sleep $((RANDOM/8192))
```

then

```
$ ./scriptA
Submiting B command group at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:07 EDT 2016
Continuing to work at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:07 EDT 2016
user@host$ Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:07 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:10 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:11 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:12 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:13 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:15 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:15 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:18 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:18 EDT 2016
Starting B at: Mon Oct 17 19:50:18 EDT 2016
```

Comment: I think OP means synchronously with FIFO, but we'll probably never know as it looks like a drive-by question.  **;-)**

Comment: As a matter of fact, when script A wants to start script B, script A adds a line to a file, (PUSH).  T this line contains all information for script B.  Script B retrieves the first line of this file and when the retrieved line is not empty then script B executes what is asked in the retrieved line.  the file acts as a FIFO and